# How to send array to PHP with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have got this array

```
var Age=[$(".AJcountry").find(".focus").html()];
```

and this AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '../connect.php',
    data: "CountS=" + Age,
    success: function (dataa)
    {
        alert(dataa);
    }
});
```

But it only return the last selected item.How can i send to PHP everything inside array

Comment: What does `console.log(Age);` return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop

```
var Age=[];

$(".AJcountry").find(".focus").each(function(){
Age.push($(this).html());
});
```

in ajax:

```
data: {CountS:Age},
```

in php you do :

```
echo $_GET['CountS'][0];//get the first
```

or a loop

Comment: It says wait 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an object to the `data` property of `$.ajax` then jQuery will serialise it for you:

```
data: { CountS: Age }
```

Also note that while you are putting the `html()` value of the `.focus` element in an array, that array will *always* only contain one string element, so the array itself seems completely redundant in this case.

Comment: Actually madalin's way worked for me.I tried your answer it returned blank

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array to JSON like this:

```
var json = JSON.Stringify(Age);
```

Then send it via AJAX like you are doing:

```
data: {CountS: Age}
```

In the back-end convert the JSON back to an array like so:

```
$json = json_decode($_GET['CountS']);
```

This method converts the data to a very small text string before transmitting it. The PHP back-end then converts it back to an array. This method also works with most objects in JavaScript. You can read more about JSON [here](http://www.json.org/)